# How can I enforce first person view in Minecraft 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a map where you cant go in 3rd person, however when I check Google and Arqade it either don't find a answer, or it no longer works.

This is all in Minecraft Java Edition 1.12.2

Comment: I don't think you can, what do you need it for?

Comment: maybe maybe not, it was possible before if it is now i need to know.

Comment: Not fully possible without modding or maybe server plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using commands because third person is a client POV. However, you can give yourself invisible blocks with the:
"
/give *your username* barrier
"
command by writing it in the chat. (That is, assuming you have access to commands.)
Once you have these barrier blocks, you place them one block above the player everywhere you do not want the player to have f5 mode. You see, barrier blocks are invisible, but they have a collision blocks: they count as solid blocks. There are advantages and disadvantages:
when the player enters third person, their view will be blocked like they had a block above their heads, even though it looks like they don't. However, they can still use it horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a resource pack with a big 3d model replacing a hat making 3rd person a blackscreen essentially. (However I am not sure this will work for both back and front 3rd person).

Note: I suggest using Blockbench for this as it's going to make the whole process a lot easier.